# Strimzi Kubernetes Kafka Cluster ID not matching

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

I am currently facing a strange behaviour which I cannot really grab.

I created a kafka cluster and everything worked fine. Then I wanted to rebuild on a different namespace so I deleted everything (kafka CRD, strimzi yaml and devices) and created everything new in the different namespace.

Now I am getting constant error messages (kafka is not starting up):

```
The Cluster ID oAF2NGklQ0mF2_f3U0oJuw doesn't match stored clusterId Some(Gjb2frSRSS-v6Bpjx-dyqg) in meta.properties. The broker is trying to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.
```

Thing is: I am not aware, that I kept some state between both namespaces (drop everything, formated filesystem). I even restarted the kubernetes cluster node to make sure that even emptyDir (strimzi-tmp) is reset, but no success...

The IDs stay the same (after reboot, rebuild of filesystem, drop and recreate of application).

My Cluster Config:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: kafka-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.1.0
    replicas: 1
    listeners:
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
        authentication:
          type: tls
    authorization:
      type: simple
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 1
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 1
      default.replication.factor: 1
      min.insync.replicas: 1
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.1"
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 20Gi
      deleteClaim: false
    jmxOptions: {}
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 1
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 20Gi
      deleteClaim: false
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, that the wrong persistent volume was mounted. The pod seems not to mount the requested iSCSI volume, but some local storage.